# Regex class and test in C# .Net

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I've copied a RegEx that's working in Javascript. But when I run it in C# it returns false. I'm not sure if it's my code iteslf that's incorrect or if it is the RegEx. This is my code.

```
bool isValid = true;

string nameInput = "Andreas Johansson";
string emailInput = "email@gmail.com";
string passwordInput = "abcABC123";

string namePattern = @"^[A-z]+(-[A-z]+)*$";
string emailPattern = @"^([\w-\.]+@([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]{2,4})?$";
string passwordPattern = @"^(?=.*\d+)(?=.*[a-zA-Z])[0-9a-zA-Z!@#$%]{6,50}$";
Regex nameRegEx = new Regex(namePattern);
Regex emailRegEx = new Regex(emailPattern);
Regex passwordRegEx = new Regex(passwordPattern);

if (model.CreateFullName.Length < 3 || !nameRegEx.IsMatch(nameInput))
                    isValid = false;

if (model.CreateEmail.Length < 3 || !emailRegEx.IsMatch(emailInput))
                    isValid = false;

if (model.CreatePassword.Length < 3 || !passwordRegEx.IsMatch(passwordInput))
                    isValid = false;
```

Thankful for inputs!

Comment: Show values you're testing your regex with

Comment: Edited, added input values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should remove boundary slashes from pattern definitions. They are required for regex objects in javascript not .NET. e.g.:

```
string namePattern = @"^[A-z]+(-[A-z]+)*$";
string emailPattern = @"^([\w-\.]+@([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]{2,4})?$";
string passwordPattern = @"^(?=.*\d+)(?=.*[a-zA-Z])[0-9a-zA-Z!@#$%]{6,50}$";
```

UPDATE: you fixed them in your edit.

The name pattern still does not account for spaces in the input. Try following instead:

```
^[A-z]+([-\s][A-z]+)*$
```

Also note that `[A-z]` is not a correct pattern for matching alphabet letters. Use `[A-Za-z]` for matching ASCII alphabet letters, or `\p{L}` for matching any unicode letter.

The problem for `[A-z]` is that it matches these character too that reside after `Z` and before `a`:

```
[\]^_`
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it made email and password work, I've made an edit with the input values I use if you see anything in the name regex